# Unmarshalling complex json into complex data struct fails on one sub-struct

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to unmarshal a JSON file from Darksky, and as it's fairly complex JSON I've build a struct of sub-structs.  A partial example of the structs used is:

```
  type current struct {
    Time                 uint    `json:"time"`                 //   1453402675,
    Summary              string  `json:"summary"`              //   "Rain",
    Icon                 string  `json:"icon"`                 //   "rain",
    NearestStormDistance uint    `json:"nearestStormDistance"` //   0,
    PrecipIntensity      float64 `json:"precipIntensity"`      //   0.1685,
    PrecipIntensityError float64 `json:"precipIntensityError"` //   0.0067,
    PrecipProbability    float64 `json:"precipProbability"`    //   1,
    PrecipType           string  `json:"precipType"`           //   "rain",
    Temperature          float64 `json:"temperature"`          //   48.71,
    ApparentTemperature  float64 `json:"apparentTemperature"`  //   46.93,
    Dewpoint             float64 `json:"dewPoint"`             //   47.7,
    Humidity             float64 `json:"humidity"`             //   0.96,
    WindSpeed            float64 `json:"windSpeed"`            //   4.64,
    WindBearing          int     `json:"windBearing"`          //   186,
    Visibility           float64 `json:"visibility"`           //   4.3,
    CloudCover           float64 `json:"cloudCover"`           //   0.73,
    Pressure             float64 `json:"pressure"`             //   1009.7,
    Ozone                float64 `json:"ozone"`                //   328.35
  }

  type forecastData struct {
    Latitude  float64 `json:"latitude"`  // 40.47780682531368,
    Longitude float64 `json:"longitude"` // -86.93875375799722,
    Timezone  string  `json:"timezone"`  // "America/Indiana/Indianapolis",
    Current   current
    Daily     daily
    Alerts    []alert
    Offset    int `json:"offset"` //    -4
  }
```

It unmarshals correctly into the entire structure except for the portion that goes into current.  I've played with the types, though a problem with those usually seems to effect only that specific field.  I've looked at the declarations and looked at them literally for hours.  I've put a complete example on the Go Playground at https://play.golang.org/p/XKaIxfvS8a.  At this point, I would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Your sample on playground seems to run correctly. Can you tell us what you expect to be different?

Comment: If you look at the println statements in the output, the ones from the struct current are 0.  Also, in the first line of output which shows the entire unmarshaled struct, the current struct contains all 0;s although the current values in the data file have values.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you expected?

https://play.golang.org/p/NBn0KL8DVw

If so, you forgot to define the json field for Current in this line:

```
Current   current `json:"currently"`
```

Comment: That;s it!  This has literally driven me to the brink.  I really do appreciate your help, even if I do feel like a moron right now.

Comment: Sometimes it just needs a fresh set of eyes.